# How can i understand &*(x+i)?

Tags: c++, arrays, point

This is c++ code:

```
x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
&x[i]==&*(x+i)==x+i;
```

as for `&*(x+i)`,in my opinion,`*(x+i)` is a rvalue ,why use `&`.
why?

Comment: _"why use `&.` why?"_ Ask the author, how can we read their mind? That code looks pretty nonsensical though.

Comment: Why do your think that `*(x+i)` is an rvalue? You can assign to it, e.g. `*(x+i) = 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `&x[i]==&*(x+i)==x+i;` shell show you 3 different ways on getting the address of an specific element of an array.

In your case there is an array `x` which stores 5 values. The first thing probaly looks kind of familiar to you. `x[i]` will get the `i`-th element of the `x` and by using the *address-of-operator* you will get the address of the `i`-th element of.

Let's go on to the third statement `x+i`. Since `x` is actually just a pointer pointing to the adress of the first element of the actual array in your storage you can get the adress of other elements by adding an offset to `x`. However since you're working with `x`' address you wont get the value of the 'offsetted' element but its address. To get the value you need to derefence the address by using the magical `*`. So if `&x[i]` gets the adress of the `i`th element and `x+i` does the same, `*(x+i)` will do the same thing as `x[i]`. It will get the `i`th value of `x`.

No you know what the adress-of-operater `&` and the *derefencing-operator* `*`. Theirefore the second statement is fairly simple. `(x+i)` will get the address of the `i`th element. `*(x+i)` will get the value by dereferencing the address and `&*(x+i)` will get the adress of the derefenced address. So the second statement is the same thing as just writing `x+i`.

However the explained line will probably give you a compiler error since it should more look like this: `(&x[i]) == (&*(x+i)) && (&x[i]) == (x+i);`

Conclusion: All these things do the same thing yet slightly differently.

Comment: I just think *(x+i) is a rvalue,and can't use & before it. I'm wrong, *(x+i) is a lvalue,u are right,thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose we have this piece of code

```
int i = 0;
int x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

then this comparision is true:

```
&x[i] == &*(x+i)
```

and this comparision is also true for similar reasons.

```
&*(x+i) == x+i;
```